# Load a script dynamically within the <head> element

Tags: javascript, synchronous, dynamic-loading

Okay so I'm trying to load a backup `.js` file *synchronously* in the event of a script dependency being unavailable, and everything seems to be working fine except for the fact that said script doesn't actually load, even though the element itself with the `src` is created:

```
[etc]

<head>
<script id = 'self'>
 if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {

  function insertAfter(referenceNode, el) { 
    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(el, referenceNode.nextSibling); 
  }

  var loadjq = document.createElement('script');

  // backup CDN
  loadjq.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js'; 

  loadjq.type = 'text/javascript';
  // loadjq.async = false;

  insertAfter(document.getElementById('self'), loadjq);

 }  
</script>

// element IS created here: <script src = 'https://ajax.google...' type = 'text/...'></script>
// but nothing is executed

<script>
  console.log($); // Reference Error
</script>
</head>

[etc]
```

Do note that I have not put this within a `DOMContentLoaded` event or anything, but I feel this should be working. 
I tested with Chrome and Firefox, and it's not a caching error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load script async?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36592002/load-script-async)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asynchronous Script Loading Callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820953/asynchronous-script-loading-callback)

Comment: Damn linked to the wrong but the point is this is well covered on SO.

Comment: links appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note, this isn't ideal, however if you absolutely need to you can use the following.

Use `document.write` to achieve this synchronously.

```html
<script>
document.write(`jQuery is: ${typeof(jQuery)}.`);
</script>

<script>
document.write(`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"><\/script>`);
</script>

<script>
document.write(`jQuery is: ${typeof(jQuery)}.`);
</script>
```

Note that you cannot have `</script>` in the string directly as this will terminate the actual `script` tag.

Comment: You can, however, escape the forward-slash like `'<\/script>'` so that backticks aren't needed. Thank you, best answer.

Comment: I've fixed up the snippet as well.